# Div not positioning correctly in parent container

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in a container named #content_container.

My divs are #lightbox_block which contains a large black rectangle with 4 smaller rectangles and #advertisement_bar which is for the moment just flat.

I want #advertisement_bar to appear below #lightbox_block but it seems to be sticking to the top of #content_container. I have tried to add a relative positioning tag to force it away but it still sticks, any tips is much appreciated!

```css
#content_container {
  width: 930.75px;
  height: 620px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}
#lightbox_block {
  width: 930.75px;
  height: 324.00px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: absolute;
}
#advertisement_bar {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#0a0a0a+0,222222+80,232323+100 */
  background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(10, 10, 10, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 80%, rgba(35, 35, 35, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(10, 10, 10, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 80%, rgba(35, 35, 35, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(10, 10, 10, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 80%, rgba(35, 35, 35, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0a0a0a', endColorstr='#232323', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="content_container">

  <div id="lightbox_block">
  </div>

  <div id="advertisement_bar">
  </div>

</div>
```

**Screenshot of problem**
[image]

Comment: code snippet shows nothing

Comment: My main code is pretty big, I added just a very short version of it so you could see the CSS and HTML positioning.

Comment: @Ninja2k is this what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/1tLb7z4b/2/

Comment: Yes but for some reason it does not work in my code, see here for my original full code https://jsfiddle.net/1tLb7z4b/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with the content container and one of the margin-left values, I set the blocks to absolute, relative, relative and removed the margin-left and it works now!

Answer (score -1):

Your pen isn't working but it looks like you need to remove position `absolute;`
from `#advertisement_bar`

Answer (score -1):

You have `position absolute` in your `#advertisement_bar` CSS, `position absolute` will make it stick to the top by default unless you define a `top` or `bottom` property.

You could give it more `top` than `#light_box` or give it a different position value.

You can read more about this in the [Mozilla Developers documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: I tried that but it is still not disengaging, perhaps I should post the full code?

Answer (score -1):

You should remove `position: absolute`, because `position: absolute` takes the element out of the normal page flow. In this case, if you want two child divs into your parent container, this is one approach:

```
.parent {
width: 992px;
height: 400px;
}
.first-child {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
display: block;
}
.second-child {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
display: block;
}

<div class="parent">
<div class="first-child">Hello world</div>
<div class="second-child">Hello again</div>
</div>
```

If you insist using `position: absolute`, then you have to add `top: ~300px`..., to your second div by "forcing" it below your first div. I do not recommend it. And you also have to add `position: relative` to your parent div, so your childs are relative to the parent and not the window.

Comment: Hmmm still not working, a link to my full code has been added to my post.

Comment: @Ninja2k, I posted an update of your fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/1tLb7z4b/2/, but I still want you to consider this: https://jsfiddle.net/1tLb7z4b/3/